# A correct way to place divs side by side

Tags: css, html, css-position

I know its a noob and repeated question, but I need some answers.

I  think: 1 div with width: 100% and 2 divs inside this with width:50% each.WHy does it not fit ?

HTML:

```
<div id="top-menu">
   <div id="logo"></div>            
   <div id="menu-top"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#top-menu{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #A3238E;
}

#logo{
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background: orange;
}

#menu-top{
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background: green;
    left: 0;
}
```

I get a little blank space between the 2 divs, but I don't know how to remove it...
Also, if I set the second one with Width: 49%, it works... But with 50% it doesnt, I Guess it's because that little blank space betweem them.

How to make it work ?

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not fit"?

Comment: It doesnt stay side by side, it drops below the first div ;s

Comment: try setting margin and padding to 0 for both divs

Comment: @dmikester1 still the same ...

Comment: A very easy solution use `display:table` and `display: table-cell; to align the divs. 
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use the following:

```
#top-menu{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #A3238E;
}

#logo{
    width: 50%;
    float:left;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background: orange;
}

#menu-top{
    width: 49%;
    float:left;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background: green;
    left: 0;
}
```

Noticed I added `float:left;` to the two divs that you want side by side.  Then on your html use the following:

```
<div id="top-menu">
   <div id="logo"></div>            
   <div id="menu-top"></div>
   <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Notice I added `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` which will clear the `float:left;`.  You can use `<div style="clear:left;"></div>` to do the same thing if you would like.

Comment: And talking about "nice practice", is it a correct way to do it?

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro Not particularly; it uses in-line styles. This is considered bad practice. CSS should go in .css files.

Comment: My answer above solves the float clearing issue without inline styles.

Comment: @TylerH Well yeah I'm assuming they know to put css in the .css file.  He didn't say otherwise.  It's true if you take out the `display:inline-block;` you will get the same exact results.

Comment: @derekshull It's not safe to assume anything at StackOverflow, especially of the person asking the question :-P

Comment: @TylerH thanks for the heads up.  I just give people the benefit of the doubt unless I see otherwise that they don't know something.  so yes PlayHardGoPro you should put your CSS in the .css file.  Good job TylerH!

Comment: my mistake cause i have seen the purple piece, but it's because of 49%

Comment: @aSeptik it tripped me up for a second as well.

Comment: @derekshull I tried to put some content inside the div, with the way you showed in jsfiddle... But half of the div dropped below the first div D:

Comment: lol ok.  Don't forget to check it as correct @PlayHardGoPro Glad I could help!

Comment: `display: inline-block` is ignored when using `float: left` -- might as well remove it. (The element is set to `display: block` by the `float: left`)

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `float: right;` to `#menu-top`: http://jsfiddle.net/n5md7/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of `inline-block`: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Replace `display: inline-block;` with `float: left;`

.. and then you can add `overflow: hidden` to the #top-menu to clear the floats.

UPDATE:

You'll probably need to remove `height: 100px` from #top-menu to use the `overflow: hidden` clearfix technique.

Comment: Worked just perfect ! If I add the overflow to #top-menu, I wont need to create another div to use clear:both ? is it a correct/right way to do ? Thanks!

Comment: Absolutely (or you can use a `clearfix` class if other factors preclude the use of `overflow: hidden`).

Comment: the only problem with this solution is that by hiding the overflow also the content inside it will be hidden

Comment: @aSeptik only because there is an extraneous fixed height setting on the container.

Answer (score -1):

> - http://jsfiddle.net/UbQq9/

```
#top-menu{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #A3238E;
    display: table;
}

#logo{
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    background: orange;
}

#menu-top{
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    background: green;
}
```

Comment: This kind of display, table and table-cell. is it a good practice?

Comment: Before using this, I would make sure it works in the browsers you need to support. This is supported back to IE8. There is also some question if screen readers and other accessibility tools will read CSS display table as a table or as it is semantically in the markup. This is not a way I've done this in the past, so I'm not positive, but it's worth looking into.

Comment: @aSeptik I checked that, but I am curious about it's accessibility. I'm not saying it's not accessible, just that it's not something I've looking into, and I'm curious how accessible it is.

Comment: anyway the best should be the float:left + clear:both exept for IE6 that have a fix http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/peekaboo.html

Comment: @aSeptik ... except for the whole extra element an inline style thing.